# Auto fill form with URL not working

Tags: javascript, forms, url

I was trying to write a bit of javascript to go to a website with the form data already filled in.

This is the HTML for the site:

```
<form action="/transfer-request" method="post"> 
  <input name="_csrf" value="PcZhHftj-GInv-7mCqMprPOA_aK2HERs1G10" type="hidden"> 
  <label for="amount">Coins</label> 
  <input id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="100" min="10" step="1" required="" type="number">
  <label for="to-user">Recipient User</label> 
  <input id="to-user" name="to-user" required="" type="text">
  <a href="/transfer" class="button ">Back</a> 
  <input class="button right" type="submit"> 
  <input name="transfer-id" value="3344847d-1824-48e1-b156-8debd677a672" type="hidden"> 
</form>
```

Assume site is on `www.example.com/transfer`
I have tried modifying the URL as follows:

```
www.example.com/transfer?amount=25
```

Without any luck. Am I doing this wrong? Should this not auto fill the amount field to 25, is there a way the website is preventing me from auto filling it, or an alternative way (either through URL or javascript only) that I can accomplish this?

Comment: For such autofill to work, this should be explicitly implemented on server side or client side.

Comment: @MaratTanalin So is there no way for me to auto load the website with the form data filled in already?

Comment: If you are a developer of this website, you should implement this yourself. If you are a user, you could use a browser extension that performs such autofill or browser's built-in autofill functionality.

Comment: @MaratTanalin I am a user, and I am just looking for a way to link the site to my friends with the data filled in. A browser extension would not work, which is why I specified either through URL or javascript only in my question.

Comment: It's unlikely possible to prefill the form when sharing a link, unless your friends have an installed extension (which unlikely exists) intended to do this for the specific site/page/form.